# React Checkbox Click Event Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm working on a React application where I have a table of checkboxes, and the initial values of these checkboxes are fetched from an API. The challenge I'm currently facing is how to immediately update the UI in response to a user's interaction with the checkbox before the API response arrives, and then reconcile the UI state with the API response after it's received.

Here is the brief usecase

1. Initially, Checkbox having api boolean value
2. When a user toggle the checkboxes, the api response takes a little time to update
3. So,my objective is to assign the checkbox a temporary boolean value(baesed on toggle value) for about 10 second
4. Then assign the checkbox value from the API after 10 second

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
// Function to handle checkbox click and update control
const handleCheckboxClick = async (controlId, property, value, setLocalState) => {
  // Create the patchData object with the updated value
  const updatedValue = !value;
  const patchData = {
    [property]: updatedValue,
  };

  try {
    // Send the PATCH request to update the control
    setUpdateLoading(true);
    await http.patch(
      `${baseURL}/threat-catalog/control-analysis/${controlId}`,
      patchData
    );

    // Trigger an immediate refetch of the data
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([
      'apiData',
      `${baseURL}/threat-catalog/control-analysis?businessProcessId=${processId}`,
    ]);

    // Temporarily update the local state with the opposite value
    // This will make the checkbox appear to change for 10 seconds
    setLocalState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [property]: !value,
    }));

    // After 10 seconds, revert the local state to the API value
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLocalState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [property]: value,
      }));
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds delay (10000 milliseconds)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
    // Handle error
  }
};
```

**In my JSX code, I'm calling handleCheckboxClick as follows:**

```
<input
  id={`applicable-checkbox-${controls.id}`}
  type="checkbox"
  defaultChecked={controls?.is_applicable}
  checked={localState[controls.id]?.is_applicable || false}
  onClick={() => handleCheckboxClick(controls.id, 'is_applicable', 
  localState[controls.id]?.is_applicable)}
/>
```